# Bigquery Clean records when value is empty

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to clean the related records when type value is empty, please see below sample data:

| session | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 123 |  |
| 456 | pdp |

I've written below:

```
select *
from table 
where Type is not null
```

However the "is not null" didn't clean empty record, it still returns the exact same sample table. Any suggestions how to make it right? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table where Type is not null or TRIM(Type) = ''
```

In this case, the value is not `null`, it is `empty` rather than `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question, can use length (Page_Type) > 0 to workaround